# Wireless control of switches

Tags: wireless, control

This is slightly modified diagram of original one for control of DC motor using relays I got in this community. I added flyback diodes and battery for relay coils:

[image]

My question is, is it possible to wireless control switches S1 and S2 from distance of few meters and what is easiest way to do it, if it is possible?

EDIT:
I modified circuit, now there are only two wires for motor and limiters.
Functions of RLY1 and RLY2 are also changed: when RLY1 is "activated" (RLY2 "deactivated") it will move motor in one direction, when RLY2 is "activated" (RLY1 "deactivated") it will move motor in opposite direction.
[image]

Comment: Are you aware there's a schematic button on the toolbar? You could have copied my schematic and edited it with that! The easiest way to do it would be to look for an infra-red remote with two channels. A garage door open / close remote, for example.

Comment: I'm new here and I didn't know that. Sorry. Thanks for suggestion about infra-red remot, I will look for it.

Comment: @transistor, can I send two commands AT SAME TIME using IR? It is neccessary to control both S1 and S2 at same time, S1 for turn on and S2 for direction...

Comment: I think it's time for you to do some research. ;^)

Comment: @transistor, Ok. I modified circuit, you can refresh to take a look :) There is no need now to send two commands at same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest would be to use a remote control kit available from many sources. They include a "keychain" size transmitter with 4 buttons, and a receiver board with four relays.  They are quite inexpensive and ready to use out of the box.

Just for reference, here are some examples:

[image: Example from MPJA]

[image: Example from Ebay]

Comment: Thanks for answer. What is difference between two kits you posted? What is purpose of relays in second kit?

Comment: Those are just two of many more types.  The purpose for the relays is for applications where you are just remotely turning four things on or off.  The first example would be the kind where you could have it drive your already existing relays.

Comment: I asked because I thought there is some special function of relays in second type. Because I already have them it looks like first type would be ok :)